# Filtering the list in the list

Tags: java, regex, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a list of objects A in which each object A contains a list of other objects B.
How to filter list of objects B and return list of objects A?

```
class A {
    private String group;
    private List<B> b;
}

class B {
    private String name;
}
```

I know how to use one list filtering:

```
listB
.stream()
.filter(b -> "123".equals(b.getName)))
.collect(toList());
```

But how do I filter list B for each object A?
At the output I want to get a new list of objects A after modification (filtering).
I don't want to change the original list.

Comment: What do you mean by this `How to filter list of objects B and return list of objects A?`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I have a list of objects A. I want to filter in each object A a list of objects B. Then I want to get a new list of objects A after modification.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `forEach`:

```
listA.forEach(a -> {
    a.setB(a.getB().stream()
        .filter(b -> "123".equals(b.getName)))
        .collect(toList());
});
```

@Naman suggests even more concise and elegant way:

```
listA.forEach(a -> a.getB().removeIf(b -> !"123".equals(b.getName)));
```

Comment: `a.setB(a.getB()...` can be replaced with `a.b.removeIf`

Comment: @Naman you mean the inner stream, right?

Comment: yes, that is where objects are getting mutated primarily

Comment: @Naman I let myself add it to my answer, thank you!

Comment: you don't need to set while mutating the underlying collection itself with the use of `removeIf`

Comment: @Naman once again you're right, I use this method way to rarely

Comment: @Andronicus But this causes a permanent change of the list. I want to get a new list after modifications.
The original list of objects A should remain unchanged.